# Unable to retrieve/remove/add tiles when more than 13 tiles are on the band

Tags: microsoft-band

I'm having a problem with the Band SDK Samples when I have more than 13 tiles enabled on my band (it now supports 20). Whenever I try to do something with the TileManager, I get a BandIOException telling me it attempted to read past the end of the stream.

I have noticed this on two Band 2's, connected to different phones, on the latest Windows Insider Fast Ring Builds (10.0.14295.1000). Band firmware version is 2.0.4441.0, hardware version 26.

Is this a known problem? Do I have to wait for an SDK update to support more tiles?

Kind Regards,

Maarten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Band SDK release notes](https://developer.microsoftband.com/bandSDK/ReleaseNotes) and my experience on iOS, it appears that we do need to wait for a new SDK. If there 12 or more tiles you cannot inject more presently.